# Group by key collection type in Apache Beam pipeline

Tags: go, apache-beam, dataflow

I have a pipeline in Apache Beam Go SDK.

```
pcoll := beam.GroupByKey(s, src)
```

The thing is that after GroupByKey transformation I want to process it further with ParDo transformation. And I have the problem with type since Go want me to define ParDo function input as follows:

```
value CoGBK<[]uint8,[]uint8>
```

but there is no type CoGBK in Go. Is there a way do define such type in Apache Beam Go SDK?

Comment: Based on [this](https://godoc.org/github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam#CoGroupByKey) and [this](https://godoc.org/github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam#ParDo), I would say that your statement «Go want me to define ParDo function input as follows: `value CoGBK<[]uint8,[]uint8>`» is false as the 3rd argument to `beam.ParDo` is `PCollection`, and that's exactly what `beam.[Co]GroupByKey` return.

Comment: One thing to consider: the docs of the Beam's Go SDK appears to be written unfortunately sloppy in this regard: they appear to mix terminology from Java (the lingua franca of any Apache-hosted project) and Go, and that only works well, when the reader is reasonably well-versed in both languages to that they understand that `CoGBK<[]uint8,[]uint8>` is a parabole, not the definition of a real type.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions I followed them, however I'm still stuck.

`pcoll := beam.GroupByKey(s, src)`

And now you want to apply another transform on PCollection, let's say ParDo

`res, err := beam.TryParDo(s, &exampleFn{}, pcoll)`

And exampleFn `func (fn *exampleFn) ProcessElement (x beam.PCollection, y beam.PCollection, emit func([]bytes))`

And Go SDK expects x, y type to match CoGBK<[]uint8,[]uint8>, but I can't find anywhere how to achieve it, there are examples in learning/katas, but they don't process anything after GroupByKey transformation.

Comment: Ok, when we have a message that we need value `CoGBK<[]uint8,[]uint8>` type, what we actually should do is apply the following transform:
`beam.ParDo0(s, func(key []uint8, values func(*[]uint8) bool) {}, pcoll)`
And that's interpreted by Go as CoGBK<[]uint8,[]uint8>.

This question should be mark as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, when we have a message that we need value `CoGBK<[]uint8,[]uint8>` type, what we actually should do is apply the following transform:
`beam.ParDo0(s, func(key []uint8, values func(*[]uint8) bool) {}, pcoll)`
And that's interpreted by Go as `CoGBK<[]uint8,[]uint8>`.